# Running db.repairDatabase() from mongodb-native in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I can run db.repairDatabase() from the mongodb shell but I can't find an example on running the same command from node.js app using the mongodb-native module. How can I run "repairDatabase" with executeDbCommand method?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
db.command({repairDatabase:1}, function(err, result) {

});
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to see what the mongo javascript shell does, just remove the parenthesis and it will show you the underlying code:

```
> db.repairDatabase
function () {
    return this._dbCommand({repairDatabase:1});
}
//This basically...
>return this.getCollection("$cmd").findOne({repairDatabase:1});
```

See [this code](https://github.com/christkv/node-mongodb-native/blob/master/lib/mongodb/db.js#L774) in the driver for the implementation.

Comment: findOne is a completely different method. repairDatabase is a command to check database consistency and it's not related to findOne method.