# Collection.rawDatabase().repairDatabase is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, meteor

how to repair database in Meteor. Below is the code that I am executing right now.

```
Meteor.methods({
  'repairDB'(){
    Users.rawDatabase().repairDatabase();
    return true;
  }
});
```

Below is the error that I am facing.

```
I20170630-18:43:57.601(5.5)? Exception while invoking method 'repairDB' TypeErro
r: Users.rawDatabase(...).repairDatabase is not a function
I20170630-18:43:57.604(5.5)?     at [object Object].Meteor.methods.repairDB (imp
orts/startup/server/methods.js:46:33)
I20170630-18:43:57.607(5.5)?     at maybeAuditArgumentChecks (packages/ddp-serve
r/livedata_server.js:1737:12)
I20170630-18:43:57.609(5.5)?     at packages/ddp-server/livedata_server.js:719:1
9
I20170630-18:43:57.612(5.5)?     at [object Object]._.extend.withValue (packages
\meteor.js:1122:17)
I20170630-18:43:57.633(5.5)?     at packages/ddp-server/livedata_server.js:717:4
0
I20170630-18:43:57.635(5.5)?     at [object Object]._.extend.withValue (packages
\meteor.js:1122:17)
I20170630-18:43:57.638(5.5)?     at packages/ddp-server/livedata_server.js:715:4
6
I20170630-18:43:57.639(5.5)?     at [object Object]._.extend.protocol_handlers.m
ethod (packages/ddp-server/livedata_server.js:689:23)
I20170630-18:43:57.641(5.5)?     at packages/ddp-server/livedata_server.js:559:4
3
```

Comment: You can probably execute it using a db command. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9358108/268093).

Answer (score 0):

I used `Users.rawDatabase().command({repairDatabase:1}).then(d => console.log(d));`

I received below output:

```
=> App running at: http://localhost:3000/
   Type Control-C twice to stop.

I20170630-20:23:05.462(5.5)? { ok: 1 }
```